# Why my about page in Pelican returns 404?

Tags: pelican

I cannot figure out Pelican. I want to add the `/about` page. I added the `about.md` file to `/content/pages`:

```
Template: about.html
title: about us
# this is content of about us
```

and I have a template: `themes/simple/templates/about.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>About Us</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

in my pelicanconf.py I added:

```
PAGE_URL = '/{slug}.html'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = '/{slug}.html'
```

when I go to localhost:8000/about I got 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familliar with Pelican, but what happens if you go to `localhost:8000/about.html`?  For a `/about` endpoint to work you'd need to have a webserver listening for that path, or for it to understand a default document (e.g. `index.html`) and to generate your about page as a default doc under the about path; i.e. `/about/index.html`

Comment: Maybe setting `PAGE_URL` to `/{slug}` would handle your requirement (i.e. having the web server listen for that specific path)?

Comment: it doesn't change anything I'm afraid.